# Why ToStringBuilder(ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE) adding quotes before and after object? is it True

Tags: java, json, apache-commons

i want to send json request with my java classes but When i try to send my jsonObject, I think the outgoing object went wrong.

This is true object:

```
{
    "brandCode":659599,
    "isNotAutoSendIYS": "false",
    "consentData": {
        "consentDate":"2020-07-20 00:00:00",
        "source":"HS_MESAJ",
        "status":"ONAY",
        "retailerCode":null,
        "retailerAccess":[],
        "recipient":"ornek@mysoft.com.tr",
        "recipientType":"BIREYSEL",
        "type":"EPOSTA"
    }
}
```

This is my jsonObject from class:

```
{
"brandCode":659599,
"isNotAutoSendIYS":false,
"consentData":"{\"consentDate\":\"2020-07-20 00:00:00\"
,\"source\":\"HS_MESAJ\",
\"status\":\"ONAY\",
\"retailerCode\":null,
\"retailerAccess\":[\"\"],
\"recipient\":\"ornek@mysoft.com.tr\",
\"recipientType\":\"BIREYSEL\",
\"type\":\"EPOSTA\"}"
}
```

If you have noticed, double quotes are opened after the consentData object and double quotes at the end of the object are closed. How can i fix this situation or this situation is true ? I'am using ToStringBuilder class.

This ConsentDataReqType.class :

```
public String toStringValidate(){
        return new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE).append("brandCode", brandCode).append("isNotAutoSendIYS", isNotAutoSendIYS).append("consentData", consentData.toStringValidate()).toString();
    }
```

This ConsentData.class:

```
public String toStringValidate(){
        return new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE).append("consentDate", consentDate).append("source", source).append("status", status)
                .append("retailerCode",retailerCode).append("retailerAccess",retailerAccess).append("recipient",recipient).append("recipientType",recipientType)
                .append("type",type).toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
.append("consentData", consentData.toStringValidate())
```

As far as `append` is concerned, the value being appended is a string, and so must be escaped. There is no way to know that it is actually a JSON value and can be inserted 'raw'.

If you want JSON, I would use a real JSON library, e.g. Gson.

If you just need a string which is unique for objects which have different values for their members you could do:

```
public String toStringValidate() {
            return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this, new RecursiveToStringStyle() {
                {
                    setUseIdentityHashCode(false);
                }
            }).build();
        }
```

Comment: Yes this works but why ToStringBuilder working wrong or where am I do wrong?

Comment: I've added an explanation. I think ToStringBuilder is just not designed to do hierarchical JSON generation.